# Can someone help explain a function to me in this Python program

Tags: python, function, statistics, dice

I am trying to learn how to use algorithms and statistics in more complex (but not too complex) Python programs.
I have been looking up some interesting examples that I want to try and make myself, and I found this one on Github. Sadly, I have not been able to establish contact with the person who made it, so I was hoping maybe someone here could explain something for me.
I understand MOST of the program. It is pretty much a more advanced 3-player dice roll, which returns a statistic of what dice has the best and worst chance of winning depending on what the opponent picks.
Let me show you the whole code first.

```
    from random import randint

rounds = 100
dice = {
    "red": [0, 0, 4, 4, 8, 8],
    "green": [2, 2, 3, 3, 7, 7],
    "blue": [1, 1, 5, 5, 6, 6]
}


def runGame(p1, p2):
    die1 = dice[p1]
    die2 = dice[p2]

    return 1 if die1[randint(0, 5)] > die2[randint(0, 5)] else 2


def getWinner(r, b, g):
    if max(r, b, g) == r:
        return "red"
    elif max(b, g) == b:
        return "blue"
    else:
        return "green"


def getLoser(r, b, g):
    if min(r, b, g) == r:
        return "red"
    elif min(b, g) == b:
        return "blue"
    else:
        return "green"


# Simulate all possible game states with two players

# the key represents the die chosen by opponents, the value is itself a dict with win rates
# eg {"blue" : 0.45, "green" : 0.68}
results = {
    "red": {},
    "blue": {},
    "green": {}
}

print("Running %d simulations for every combination of two players..." % rounds, end="")

for opponent in results.keys():

    remaining = list(dice.keys())
    remaining.remove(opponent)

    for player in remaining:
        wins = 0

        for _ in range(rounds):
            if runGame(player, opponent) == 1:
                wins += 1

        results[opponent][player] = wins / rounds

print("completed.")

for die in dice.keys():
    rem = list(dice.keys())
    rem.remove(die)

    if results[die][rem[0]] > results[die][rem[1]]:
        print("If opponent chooses the %s dice, we should choose the %s dice, giving us %.2f%% chance of victory, "
              "as opposed to %.2f%% chance with the %s dice." % (die, rem[0], results[die][rem[0]] * 100, results[die][
            rem[1]] * 100, rem[1]))
    else:
        print("If opponent chooses the %s dice, we should choose the %s dice, giving us %.2f%% chance of victory, "
              "as opposed to %.2f%% chance with the %s dice." % (die, rem[1], results[die][rem[1]] * 100,
                                                                results[die][rem[0]] * 100, rem[0]))

# initialise a result dictionary for the three player game
results3Player = {}
for die in dice.keys():
    results3Player[die] = {
        "wins": 0,
        "losses": 0
    }

print("\nNow running %d simulations for 3 players" % rounds)

for _ in range(rounds):
    # Simulate the 3 player game
    red = dice["red"][randint(0, 5)]
    blue = dice["blue"][randint(0, 5)]
    green = dice['green'][randint(0, 5)]

    winner = getWinner(red, blue, green)
    loser = getLoser(red, blue, green)

    results3Player[winner]['wins'] += 1
    results3Player[loser]['losses'] += 1

min = 0
max = 0

minDie = None
maxDie = None

for die in dice.keys():

    # Find the maximum winner and maximum loser

    if results3Player[die]['wins'] > max:
        max = results3Player[die]['wins']
        maxDie = die

    if results3Player[die]['losses'] > min:
        min = results3Player[die]['losses']
        minDie = die

print("The die most likely to win is %s with %.2f%% probability of winning" %(maxDie, max*100/rounds))
print("The die most likely to lose is %s with %.2f%% probability of losing" %(minDie, min*100/rounds))
```

There are two parts of this code I still don't understand.

```
def runGame(p1, p2):
    die1 = dice[p1]
    die2 = dice[p2]

    return 1 if die1[randint(0, 5)] > die2[randint(0, 5)] else 2
```

If dice 1 returns a number between 0 and 5 which is larger than what dice 2 returns, then the program will return 1. If not, it will return 2.
What does 1 and 2 mean in this case?

Then there is this part

```
for opponent in results.keys():

    remaining = list(dice.keys())
    remaining.remove(opponent)

    for player in remaining:
        wins = 0

        for _ in range(rounds):
            if runGame(player, opponent) == 1:
                wins += 1

        results[opponent][player] = wins / rounds

print("completed.")
```

If I understand it correctly. "Remaining" represents the list of values inside our dice dictionary. When the player and opponent win, a new value will be added to the dictionary.
But I am unsure what "remaining.remove(opponent)" means. 
In what way is the opponent removed?

Answer (score 1):

> What does 1 and 2 mean in this case?

`1` means that the player represented by `p1` won, and `2` means the player represented by `p2` won.

> But I am unsure what `remaining.remove(opponent)` means. In what way is the opponent removed?

It's simply being removed from that list. The loop `for player in remaining:` has this opponent play a game against each player, and it wouldn't make sense to have a player play against themself. So we remove the player from the list first.

Another way to do it would have been to just skip that player in the loop:

```
players = list(results.keys())
for player in players:
    for opponent in players:
        if player == opponent:
            continue # don't play against yourself
        wins = 0
        for _ in range(rounds):
            if runGame(player, opponent) == 1:
                wins += 1
        results[opponent][player] = wins/rounds
```